# Invalid Argument Error when using ONNX Runtime. Am I even using the right code?

Tags: python, random-forest, onnx, onnxruntime

I am working on applying a machince learning model exported as an ONNX to some real time data but am having trouble following the documentation as to how to do that.

The model has been successfully output and can be reimported into my Python code. I then will grab a dataset to apply the model too that follows the same gathering and transformation steps that went into the training an testing sets.

When running the code I see the folloing error

```
InvalidArgument: [ONNXRuntimeError] : 2 : INVALID_ARGUMENT : Got invalid dimensions for input: float_input for the following indices
 index: 1 Got: 1 Expected: 4
 Please fix either the inputs or the model.
```

Below is code that I am utiziling to try to apply the ONNX. The X dataset starts as a 183x20000 dataframe, and I am converting the top row of it into a numpy array to pass into the Model for inference. I was expecting to see a single score output for this row. Instead I see the above failure. I want to note too that the X dataset follows all the transformation steps of the training/test data that went into construction of the model in the first place.

```
import pandas as pd
import pyodbc 
import datetime
import numpy
import onnxruntime as rt

data = pd.read_sql(data_sql,cnxn)
#additional transformations here
X = data.drop('Field_T',axis=1)

sess = rt.InferenceSession("Importedrf_iris.onnx")

input_name = sess.get_inputs()[0].name
output_name = sess.get_outputs()[0].name


x = X.iloc[:,[0]].to_numpy()
print(type(x))
x=x.astype(numpy.float32)
 #Grabs the top row of the query result and converts it to a numpy array
res = sess.run([output_name], {input_name: x})[0]
print(res)
```

To be frank though, this is new territory for me and I am unsure if I am using the right code to run the ONNX model to begin with.